# Cookie not working on server though working fine in local

Tags: php, cookies

I'm attempting to get the value of email cookie that I've set in another file. For setting cookie following code is there:

`setcookie('email', $_SESSION['email'], time()+3600*24*30, 'www.example.com');`

In another file, I'm trying to call this cookie, I'm using,

`$email=$_COOKIE["email"];`

However it doesn't seem to set value of that to $email variable, however when I attempt to use the value of $email in other queries, it's working fine.
I put all the code of mine here so that not to be ambiguous.

```
`$email=$_COOKIE['email'];`
```

`$result= mysql_query("select firstname from users where email='$email'");`

`$firstname=mysql_result($result,0);`

`echo $email;`

`$result2= mysql_query("select userid from users where email='$email'");`

`$cus_id=mysql_result($result2,0);`

`echo $cus_id;`

`$result3=mysql_query("select count(*) from cart where userid='$cus_id'");`

`$proInCart=mysql_result($result3,0);`

`echo $proInCart;`

So values of $email & $cus_id are not printing but $proInCart is working perfectly fine. Can anybody help in this situation?
One more thing, it's just not working on server, on local, everything works like a charm.

Comment: It's done already. Problem was with setting cookies as headers had already been sent in that file, cookies were not saving.
Now done.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done already. Problem was with setting cookies as headers had already been sent in that file, cookies were not saving.
Now done.:)